# How to access Gravitee API ,HTTP CALLOUT context variable in Gravitee API Groovy Script

Tags: groovy, gravitee

How to access Gravitee HTTP CALLOUT context variable in Gravitee Groovy Script

- name  : callout-attribute
- value : {#jsonPath(#calloutResponse.content, '$.field')}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the complete callout body into an attribute you can configure the callout policy to add a variable callout-attribute with {#calloutResponse.content}

Then in the groovy policy you can access it with context.attributes['callout-attribute']